# Does SharePoint provides all the features related to user access permission like view,edit, delete, download document?

Tags: sharepoint, document, user-roles

I want to use SharePoint for Document Sharing. 
I want all these features :

1. User access permission settings.
2. User can download Sub document but not main document.
3. One document can contain links for sub documents so I need different permissions for all those sub documents as well.
4. Different permissions for view,modify, delete and download document for main                     document as well as sub documents.
5. Different access rights to admin for uploading documents.

Answer (score 0):

I would need more information on your environment and requirements but the answer for your question in short is you would need Information Rights Management. This granularity of permissions is not supported by SharePoint based on your comment.

Comment: Thanks STORM for your answer. The Scenario is that I want to upload documents and those document may contain some links of other documents. user can have permission to download and edit those sub documents but not main document or he/she might download main document but not sub document. User can have permission to edit the document or delete the document or he will have read only access. basically I need some custom permissions.

Comment: Such fine grained permissions are not possible with SharePoint. You would need Information Rights Management. I have modified my post above.

Comment: Ok so how to link this Information Rights Management with SharedPoint.

Comment: The Information Rights Management System would not link to SharePoint. It is a seaprate system in your infrastructure and is "attached" to the Office documents. Everytime a user opens a document for example, tries to print it etc. the system checks if the user is allowed to do that. I would suggest that you read a little bit about IRM in the internet.